# How to remove empty row in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm just trying to solve simple examples to improve my skill on writing queries in BigQuery. In the below example, 
I don't know how to remove the empty row.

```
with table1 as(
select "box_1" box, "yellow" colours union all
select "box_1" box, "green" colours union all
select "box_2" box, "blue" colours union all
select "box_2" box, "blue" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "red" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "green" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "blue" colours
)
select array(select box from unnest(x)y where "blue" in unnest(x) limit 1 )box_containing_blue 
from(select box,array_agg(if(colours="blue",colours,null)ignore nulls )x 
from table1 group by box)
```

Comment: it is hard to improve something that makes no much sense (at least without extra details). instead of forcing us to guess - can you explain what exactly your expected output?

Comment: Row box_containing_blue  
1 box_2  
2 box_3

Comment: that's exactly what Sourygna's answer does for you - at the same time it is quite different from what your script produces :o)

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should do the trick

```
with table1 as(
select "box_1" box, "yellow" colours union all
select "box_1" box, "green" colours union all
select "box_2" box, "blue" colours union all
select "box_2" box, "blue" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "red" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "green" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "blue" colours
)
select array(select box from unnest(x)y where "blue" in unnest(x) limit 1 )as box_containing_blue 
from(select box,array_agg(if(colours="blue",colours,null)ignore nulls )x 
from table1 group by box
having x is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you really try to achieve with that query. 
But if this is what I believe, I think you could simplify it like this:

```
with table1 as(
select "box_1" box, "yellow" colours union all
select "box_1" box, "green" colours union all
select "box_2" box, "blue" colours union all
select "box_2" box, "blue" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "red" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "green" colours union all
select "box_3" box, "blue" colours
)
select distinct box as box_containing_blue from table1 where colours = "blue"
```